# Phirehose credentials

Tags: php, api, twitter, streaming, phirehose

Just a noob question but really a blocker.

I'm trying to use Twitter's streaming API. I came across PhireHose.

I was able to setup and uploaded to a web facing webserver, however my question is where do I get this "USERNAME" and "PASSWORD" credential? I tried my Twitter credentials but it still says

> Phirehose: HTTP failure x of 20 connecting to stream: HTTP ERROR 401: Unauthorized

Comment: its the twitter credentials according to the docs. can you try a different twitter account?

Answer (score 0):

Things to check:

1) Is your twitter application set up correctly at dev.twitter.com, and 
are your API keys set correctly?

2) Check your arg_separator.output setting, it should be set to '&', not 
'&'.

3) Examine the output of each step of the OAuth signing process, and see 
if it matches the process outlined in the Twitter OAuth documentation. 
Look for character encoding differences, especially.

4) Contact Twitter and see if your IP was blacklisted.

Some actual code would be nice and would actually help!

Answer (score 0):

The username and password that you are supposed to use with Phirehose are not ou account's credentials, but the tokens generated by Twitter APIs.
Go to http://developer.twitter.com and generate a new app.
In the tab "Keys and access tokens" you'll then be able to find the first two keys that you need to use:

```
Consumer Key (API Key)
Consumer Secret (API Secret)
```

They correspond to the Phirehose

```
define("TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY", "");
define("TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET","");
```

You then have to have a look at the "Your access token" section, where you'll find

```
Access Token
Access Token Secret
```

That are the 2 strings that you'll need to use in:

```
define("OAUTH_TOKEN", "");
define("OAUTH_SECRET", "");
```

Hope this helps,
S.